# Magento get latest products added in the store

Tags: magento-1.9, product

how i can get the newly created products in the store ?

Products collections:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
 ->addUrlRewrite();
```

in my store i have a 20 **products** and i've **added** a product named **test**, but when print the collection value i've got all the products i want to get newly created products added in my case named **test**.
I don't want to get last added Product, 
If I add multiple products, it should give me multiple products collection.

Any solutions ?

Comment: Do you want to get last added product?

Comment: yes i want to get last product added to the store not all products

Comment: Can latest product be multiple or only a single?

Comment: what do you mean about multiple or single ?

Comment: can be multiple product not first item

Comment: for example i have 20 products in my store and i added 2 new products my question i want to get last 2 products added to my store :)

Comment: @JaiminSutariya please check the answer of given question same as he want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this, It will give you last added item of last 7 days. You just have to define days that how much older product you want.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
umask(0);
$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:m:s');

$startDate =  Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d 0:0:0', strtotime($date." -7 days"));

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
 ->getCollection()
 ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $startDate, 'to' => $date));
 $collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i have a problem when calling `$date = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d h:m:s');` it's not working because my file php in the root of `magento` folder.

Comment: Try updated answer, It will work on root file also. Just manage the "Mage.php" include path in proper way.

Comment: Yes it's working perfect :)